# Interacting with google docs after logging into my google market apps - how

Tags: php, google-docs, google-apps

Hi guys I have a google apps account set up and even set up a simple hello world application from the available samples on the [tutorial](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial.html) however I need to set it so I am able to interact with the google docs account associated with the account which has added my application.

To interact with google docs I am aware that a token is requested from google upon authentication and verification of the account however that is in a situation where you code specifically for interacting with google docs - I'm talking about having access to the google docs of the account which has added my application so my application can be used to upload documents to the google docs and make references to them - basically my application is a resource management application and it needs to be able to store references to google docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UH never mind I figured out ... next time I'll follow the documentation more carefully :(